# Recover files from one drive from a raid1 array

Tags: mount, hard-drive, raid

A couple years ago I created a raid 1 array using two 1TB drives in a computer running Ubuntu 12.04. These drives stored my files (pictures, videos and music) and acted as a server for other computers in the house. The operating system was on a different, smaller, disk. When I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 I was worried about the potential of overwriting some of these files and unplugged the two hard drives in the RAID array to be sure nothing happened to the files. I never got around to replacing them and recently got a new computer. In my naivete I thought I could just plug these two drives into a NAS and retain all the files on them. I put one drive in the NAS and it appears to have been reformated. I tried connecting the other drive back to the original computer, now running Ubuntu 14.04, but it would not mount. Any ideas for how I can rescue my pictures, videos and music? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your main goal is to recover the files, I would first try the accepted solution at [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72279/how-do-i-recover-files-from-a-single-degraded-mdadm-raid1-drive-not-enough-to). It is read-only so it sounds safe enough. Replace `/dev/sdb1` with the name of the partition on your drive. Use `parted -l` to figure out the latter.